# Is it true that $A \subset B \implies (\operatorname{int} A \subset \operatorname{int}B \iff \operatorname{int} B \not\subset \operatorname{int}A)$?

Tags: general-topology

$$A \subset B \implies \operatorname{int}A \subset \operatorname{int}B$$ is a known theorem, but does $$A \subset B\implies (\operatorname{int}A \subset \operatorname{int} B \iff \operatorname{int}B \not\subset \operatorname{int}A)?$$

$\subset$ means subset (not necessarily proper).

Comment: If by $\subset$ you mean $\subsetneq$, as opposed to $\subseteq$, then you have an implication going this way $\implies$. However, the sets could be completely disjoint, so $\operatorname{int}(B) \not\subset \operatorname{int}(A)$ does _not_ imply that $A$ is in any way contained in $B$, interiors or not.

Comment: @Arthur Oops I meant that $A\subset B$ still holds in the second one.

Comment: There are some inconsistencies here about what happens when the sets (or their interiors) happen to be equal, but as long as that's not the case, it seems true.

Comment: @Arthur Do you think this ($intB \not\subset intA$) is a proof by counter example or is there a general set theoretic and open ball proof for all cases?

Comment: What you qualify as a "known theorem" is not true if  $\subset$ stands for proper subset. E.g. if $B$ is not open then $A:=int(B)\subsetneq B$ and $int(A)=int(B)$

Comment: @drhab Could it be that the text I have here does refer to "subset", rather than "proper subset" when using $\subset$. It's not stated. This is a practice problem.

Comment: I cannot judge that, because the text is not at my disposal. Quite often $\subset$ just means "subset" (not necessarily proper). Maybe here too. In that case the "known theorem" is okay.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mean proper inclusion, then this is obviously false. Just take $A=B$, then $A\subseteq B$ and $\operatorname{int}(A)=\operatorname{int}(B)$. So inclusions are all around.

If you mean proper inclusions, this can still be false. For example if $B$ has an empty interior, $A$ must have an empty interior, in which case both are equal (so both inclusions are true). You can modify this so both $A$ and $B$ have the same, non-empty, interior to your liking as well.

If you do mean proper inclusion, then this holds in discrete spaces, where a set equals its own interior (since every set is open), in which case $A$ is a proper subset of $B$ implies that the interior of $A$ is a subset of the interior of $B$ (which is again just $A\subsetneq B$), but not vice versa.